# Does blender 2.8 have an autosave feature?

Tags: blend-files, saving

For example, I would like to save work every 30 secs or so; in a file with name file-prefix_timestamp.blend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender automatically saves your scene to a temporary file every few minutes. To get to these auto saves, just reopen Blender and go to File > Recover Auto Save.

[image]

**Auto Save**
 Temporary Files
Enables Auto Save. Tells Blender to automatically save a backup copy of your work-in-progress files to the Temporary Directory.

**Timer**
This specifies the number of minutes to wait between each Auto Save. The default value of the Blender installation is 2 minutes. The minimum is 1, and the Maximum is 60 (save every hour).